# Ignore edit reviews with ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, review, ignored-tags

For those who have 10k+ reps with ignored tags set. The "Review Edit Suggestion" feature should skip posts with those ignored tags.

In other words, if I have `java` in my ignored tags, please don't have me review edit suggestion for posts tagged `java`.

p.s. Not that I have anything against Java though :)

Answer (score 6):

Y'know, I'm not sure about this and think it could be considered [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The reason I say that is I expect most edits to [java](/questions/tagged/java) are probably not material/technical related but code formatting, title changes, tag changes or whatever. As such, having all 10k users see and look after them all might be seen as helpful since all such high rep users can judge whether an edit adds to a question or not, on a level of "that clearly improves the look/layout/spelling/grammar of the question". Also, let's suppose somebody invents Java's successor tomorrow. It'll be a young tag and need some cross-tag input.

Although I can also see the argument for allowing users to ignore tags they feel they cannot judge the quality of edits on. Perhaps a filter (my tags | all) might be a better approach?

Comment: (I just have to ask: why the tags in the answer...?)

Comment: @Arjan Couldn't resist I'm afraid. Feel free to remove them!

Comment: Nah, when I edit I can remove the upvote ;-)

Comment: Hmmm... A filter would be a better approach. Maybe I just need someway to say I neither Approve nor Reject this edit... I just want to ignore it.